# Extracting double quoted string from the given pattern

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please any one help me,

I have a string like

varchar2    b :

```
'i hav to extract second double queted string "string one".and the "Second one"'
```

Expected result : **Second One**

varchar2    a  :

```
' here is "table". "tiger" some other txt ';
```

expected result is **tiger**

from the above string patterns  i have to extract the second double quoted string accurence. Please help me in this regard i have tried many attempts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 11g, you can use [`regexp_substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858) with the new argument (that allows to match only a subexpression):

```
SQL> with data as (
  2    select 'i hav to [...] "string one".and the "Second one"' txt from dual
  3    union all
  4    select ' here is "table". "tiger" some other txt ' from dual)
  5  SELECT regexp_substr(txt,'"([^"]*)"', 1, 2, '', 1) FROM data;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(TXT,'"([^"]*)"',1,2,'',1)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Second one
tiger
```

In 10g, you could use `replace` to remove the extra `"`:

```
SQL> with data as (
  2    select 'i hav to [...] "string one".and the "Second one"' txt from dual
  3    union all
  4    select ' here is "table". "tiger" some other txt ' from dual)
  5  SELECT replace(regexp_substr(txt,'"[^"]*"', 1, 2),
  6                 '"', '')
  7    FROM data;

REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TXT,'"[^"]*"',1,2),'"','')
------------------------------------------------
Second one
tiger
```

Comment: +1 Nice, not played with regexps. I'd prob do it this way :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm):

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT 'i hav to extract second double queted string "string one".and the "Second one"'  as x FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT ' here is "table". "tiger" some other txt ' as x FROM dual)
SELECT x,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '^.*".*".*(".*").*$', '\1')
  FROM t;
```

Returns:

```
"tiger"
"Second one"
```

Hope it helps...

If you don't want the quotes then use:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '^.*".*".*"(.*)".*$', '\1')
```

Comment: +1, although the problem with regexp_replace is that it will return the whole string if there is no match (instead of NULL).

Answer (score 3):

An example using `instr()` to get index of a character (and which occurence to get) and `substr()` to take a substring of a string:

```
select 
    substr(str,
        instr(str, '"', 1,3)+1, 
        instr(str, '"', 1, 4)- instr(str, '"', 1,3)-1)
from
   (select 'here is "table". "tiger" some other txt' str from dual) strt;
```

Here `substr` uses `instr(str, '"',1,3)` to get the third occurence of '"'. It then uses `instr(str, '"', 1, 4)` to get the fourth occurence but we have to substract the position of the third '"' as this parameter is the size of the text to substring (i.e. the text between the quotes in our case).

You can improve on how we get the fourth occurence as it starts searching from position 1 again, rather than position 3.